# Unable to start MongoDB 3.0.2 service on CentOS 7

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos7

We are setting up a MongoDB server for the production environment on Amazon EC2 instance, but could not able to start the service. I've followed [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/) documentation for setup. Here are the steps, I've taken for setting up the server:

Added following to `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.0.repo`

```
[mongodb-org-3.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

And installed MongoDB 3.0.2 using `sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-3.0.2`

Created three partitions for data, journal & log:

```
sudo mkdir /mongo
sudo mkdir /mongo/data
sudo mkdir /mongo/log
sudo mkdir /mongo/journal
```

Created file system for three separate partitions:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdc
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdd
```

Created entry in `fstab` for reboot:

```
echo '/dev/xvdb /mongo/data ext4 defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0
/dev/xvdc /mongo/journal ext4 defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0
/dev/xvdd /mongo/log ext4 defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

And mounted the partitions:

```
sudo mount /mongo/data
sudo mount /mongo/journal
sudo mount /mongo/log
```

Given the permissions and created link

```
sudo chown mongod:mongod /mongo/data /mongo/journal /mongo/log
sudo ln -s /mongo/journal /mongo/data/journal
```

Configured `ulimit` & read ahead settings as given in the documentation link above. Verified permissions and partitions:

```
[deployer@prod-mongo ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  1.3G  6.8G  16% /
devtmpfs        3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.5G   57M  3.4G   2% /run
tmpfs           3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdc       7.8G   36M  7.3G   1% /mongo/journal
/dev/xvdb       150G   51M  149G   1% /mongo/data
/dev/xvdd       3.9G   16M  3.6G   1% /mongo/log
```

Permissions:

```
[deployer@prod-mongo ~]$ ll /
total 32
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root   root      7 Sep 29  2014 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   4 root   root   4096 Sep 29  2014 boot
drwxr-xr-x.  17 root   root   2860 May 11 12:11 dev
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root   root      7 Sep 29  2014 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root   root      9 Sep 29  2014 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root   root      6 Jun 10  2014 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   5 mongod mongod   41 May 11 05:06 mongo
drwxr-xr-x.  21 root   root    660 May 11 12:47 run
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root   root      8 Sep 29  2014 sbin -> usr/sbin
```

Inside `/mongo`

```
[deployer@prod-mongo ~]$ ll /mongo/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x. 3 mongod mongod 4096 May 11 07:33 data
drwxr-xr-x. 3 mongod mongod 4096 May 11 07:31 journal
drwxr-xr-x. 3 mongod mongod 4096 May 11 08:58 log
```

After changing the configurations inside `/etc/mongodb.conf`

```
logpath=/mongo/log/mongod.log
dbpath=/mongo/data
```

and when I'm doing: `sudo service mongod start`, I'm getting this error:

```
Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed. See 'systemctl status mongod.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Further logging:

```
[deployer@prod-mongo ~]$ sudo systemctl status mongod.service

mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-05-12 04:42:10 UTC; 42s ago
  Process: 22881 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 11 04:42:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.local runuser[22887]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
May 11 04:42:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.localdomain runuser[22887]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
May 11 04:42:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.local mongod[22881]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
May 11 04:42:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.local systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 11 04:42:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.local systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
May 11 04:42:10 ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.local systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
```

I've followed various articles and blog posts and StackExchange answers but didn't get any solution. Am I missing something?

**Update**: If I'm directly running the `mongodb` service from the normal user something like this: `sudo mongod --logpath ~/mongod.log --dbpath ~/mongodata`, then this service is starting properly.

We tried changing the path of the `pid` file to another directory, that didn't help either.

Comment: May be this link helpful https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/fwpzEkFv7E4.

Comment: Thank you @achuth for taking time. Although, I've already exhausted the link you provided, but that doesn't work either. Also, that solution is required when we have small size of `journal` directory. But we got 8 GB for that.

Comment: will you post the statements in mongod.log. Are you starting mongodb as root or other?

Comment: No log is being generated in the configured location i.e. `/mongo/log/mongod.log`

Comment: may be it failed to create due to permissions. Check whether the mongo user has permission to access that location(if not as root)

Comment: Yes, I've already mentioned this in the question about permission. The locations are accessible and writable via `mongod` user/group.

Comment: check this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16219

Comment: Sorry @AbhayPS, solution in that link didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, anyone encountered the same issue with MongoDB startup, here is the thread of comments https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18439. This is scheduled to be fixed in `3.1`.

Comment: Did you get this working? The ticket still shows as unresolved, and I'm running into a problem that looks superficially similar in a pretty clean centos7 instance.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, I was running the MongoDB using the command since the service was not working. After that, we have not upgraded the server or the MongoDB. @TZHX

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing you're running a flavour of Linux that uses SELinux (RHEL or CentOS 7, perhaps?)

If so, the issue is that you don't have a permissive policy on your `/mongo/` directory that permits access to daemons (like the `mongod` service.)

From Wikipedia:

> SELinux can potentially control which activities a system allows each
>   user, process and daemon, with very precise specifications. However,
>   it is mostly used to confine daemons[citation needed] like database
>   engines or web servers that have more clearly defined data access and
>   activity rights. This limits potential harm from a confined daemon
>   that becomes compromised. Ordinary user-processes often run in the
>   unconfined domain, not restricted by SELinux but still restricted by
>   the classic Linux access rights

To check whether this is the issue, try this at the shell:

`sudo setenforce 0`

This should disable SELinux policies and allow the service to run.

For a more permanent solution, see https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: Thank you @Lee for replying to this. I've already tried your solution before but not worked. It is the problem with MongoDB and Centos7, please see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18439?focusedCommentId=915785&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-915785

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem and actually found a solution for me.

In short, mongodb 3.2 uses the user 'mongod' while older versions use 'mongodb'. Some of the files and directories were owned by 'mongodb' (the older user). Once I chmod'd them to the 'mongod' user, I was able to use systemctl to control the mongod process.

More specifically, it was the "/var/log/mongodb/*" files that had the wrong user ownership.

```
root@<HOST>:# ls -alh /var/log/mongodb
total 664K
drwxr-xr-x   2 mongod  mongod  4.0K Oct 27 12:08 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root    root    4.0K Oct 27 11:51 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 3.8K Oct 27 11:48 mongod.log
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb  19K Apr 14  2016 mongod.log.2016-04-14T18-29-34
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 2.8K Apr 14  2016 mongod.log.2016-04-14T18-30-13
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb  12K Apr 14  2016 mongod.log.2016-04-14T22-27-27
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb  11K Apr 14  2016 mongod.log.2016-04-14T22-29-12
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.6K Apr 18  2016 mongod.log-20160418.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb    0 Apr 18  2016 mongod.log.2016-09-09T17-33-48
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 3.6K Sep  9 11:34 mongod.log.2016-09-09T17-34-52
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb  23K Sep  9 11:49 mongod.log.2016-09-09T17-49-49
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.0K Sep  9 11:55 mongod.log.2016-09-09T17-55-15
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.0K Sep  9 12:02 mongod.log.2016-09-09T18-02-26
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.0K Sep  9 12:13 mongod.log.2016-09-09T18-13-17
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.0K Sep  9 12:25 mongod.log.2016-09-09T18-25-01
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.2K Sep  9 12:47 mongod.log.2016-09-09T18-47-54
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.0K Sep  9 12:52 mongod.log.2016-09-09T18-52-16
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.0K Sep  9 12:54 mongod.log.2016-09-09T18-54-49
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 5.0K Sep  9 13:01 mongod.log.2016-09-09T19-01-22
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 3.0K Sep  9 13:03 mongod.log.2016-09-09T19-03-21
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 215K Sep  9 14:25 mongod.log.2016-09-09T20-25-59
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb 281K Sep 10 03:42 mongod.log-20160910
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb mongodb    0 Sep 10 03:42 mongod.log.2016-10-27T17-42-42
-rw-r-----   1 mongod  mongod     0 Sep 29 22:03 mongod.log.rpmnew
```

Notice the owner of the directory is 'mongod' (the new user) while the log files are all owned by 'mongodb' (the old user).

Comment: Oh! correct. This might be the problem but I can not test this as I no longer have access to that server. But thanks for the update and time. It will help other user.

Comment: I did `sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/log/mongodb` and it's working. thanks.