# Can't start MongoDB on CentOS7

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 empty VM.

```
> hostnamectl
...
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
          Kernel: Linux 3.18.26-guest-4-4751b4a-x86_64
    Architecture: x86_64
```

I've installed MongoDB.

```
> mongod --version
db version v3.0.11
git version: 48f8b49dc30cc2485c6c1f3db31b723258fcbf39
```

The config file:

```
> cat /etc/mongod.conf
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /mongo/logs #/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /mongo/data # (default) /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.

#security:
#operationProfiling:
#replication:
#sharding:
## Enterprise-Only Options
#auditLog:
#snmp:
```

When I try to start I get this error:

```
> service mongod start
   Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed. See 'systemctl status mongod.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details
```

and:

```
> journalctl -xn
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
avril 02 14:03:06 keystone runuser[30886]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
avril 02 14:03:06 keystone runuser[30886]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
avril 02 14:03:06 keystone mongod[30879]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
avril 02 14:03:06 keystone systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
avril 02 14:03:06 keystone systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
avril 02 14:03:06 keystone systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
```

Has anyone encountered the issue "Failed to start SYSV"?

Any help or hint is welcome.
Thanks, Paul

Comment: Are you running as root?

Comment: yes, I am logged with root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start MongoDB 3.0.2 service on CentOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182016/unable-to-start-mongodb-3-0-2-service-on-centos-7)

Comment: Provided that the answer of this question said that "This is scheduled to be fixed in 3.1", I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Same for me with 3.2.5 and Centos 7, and as i see in Jira this bug still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

The root issue is selinux permissions, which is enabled by default in CentOS 7.  This can be fixed by disabling selinux or adding the correct context to the mongo database path:

```
chcon -R -t mongod_var_lib_t /var/lib/mongod
```